# Taking Inputs in single array in multiple lines (Test Cases)

Tags: java, arrays, input, bufferedreader

I am able to take inputs in a single line in an array by the code below,but i want it to be-

3     //no of test cases

640 480 // new line

120 300 // new line

180 180 // new line

"3"is the no of test cases,the six numbers need to be stored in a single array,how should i do it?

```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  System.out.println("Enter Min Length:-");
  String lt = br.readLine();                           //Ignore this
  int length= Integer.parseInt(lt);

  System.out.println("Enter Test Cases:-");
  String temp = br.readLine();                       //test-case input
  int testcases = Integer.parseInt(temp);

  System.out.println("Enter the W and H");
  String array = br.readLine();                     //this takes only input in single line
  String No[] = array.trim().split("\\s+");
  int intarray[]= new int[testcases];

  for(int i =0;i<intarray.length;i++)
       {
         intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(No[i]);
       }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intarray));
```

Comment: You know the total no of test cases, check the readLine until equal to no of testcase and ignore the rest.

Comment: I am solving it for an online contest, i don't know the no of test-cases,for the sake of example i just kept it the way it had in an example section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
int testcases = Integer.parseInt(temp);
int i=0;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(i<=testcases)
{
   System.out.println("Enter the W and H");
   String array = br.readLine(); //this takes only input in single line
   String No[] = array.trim().split("\\s+");
   //int intarray[]= new int[testcases];

   for(int i =0;i<No.length;i++)
   {
     //intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(No[i]);
     list.add(Integer.parseInt(No[i]));
   }
   Integer[] intArray = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intarray));  
   i++;
}
```

Comment: changes- int j=0;  j++ ;  for (String No1 : No) {  list.add(Integer.parseInt(No1));} done Thank you very helpful if you are writing for online competitions and all